# Remove/hide div by click outside the popup

Tags: jquery, class, click

Trying to remove and hide div by click outside the popup. Given JS is for search box popup. When click `#search-menu` then `sly-search-form` will visible, also class `sreach-popup-back` will add for popup frame.

Just I wan to hide all class when click out side `#search-menu` or outside the search box.

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
var searchvisible = 0;            
    $("#search-menu").click(function(e){ 
//This stops the page scrolling to the top on a # link.
    e.preventDefault();
    if (searchvisible ===0) {
//Search is currently hidden. Slide down and show it.
    $("#sly-search-form").slideDown(150);
    $("#s").focus(); //Set focus on the search input field.
    searchvisible = 1; //Set search visible flag to visible.
} 
else {
//Search is currently showing. Slide it back up and hide it.
    $("#sly-search-form").slideUp(200);
    searchvisible = 0;
   }
});

// Search icon close
$('#search-menu').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('sreach-close');
$("#sly-wrapper").toggleClass('sreach-popup-back');
});

});
```

HTML:

```
<a class='fa fa-search' href='#' id='search-menu'/>
<div id='sly-search-form' style='display: none;'>
<form action='/search' onsubmit='return updateScript();'>
<input id='sly-feed-input' name='q' placeholder='Search Site ..' size='40' type='text'/>
<input id='search-btn' type='submit' value='Search'/>
</form>
```